# Android SQLite: insert() issues

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-insert

i'm trying to insert some data into a SQLite3 Database on an Android system.

This method should takes three strings and insert them into a database:

```
public void createEntry(String description, String reps, String weight) 
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(); 
    cv.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);
    cv.put(KEY_REPS, reps);
    cv.put(KEY_WEIGHT, weight);
    sqlDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);     
}
```

The columns(KEY_DESCRIPTION,..) are all defined as TEXT NOT NULL and I also added an auto incrementing column.

In my main activity I'm using this code to get input from EditText Widgets

> String description = sqlDescription.getText().toString();

then I'm creating an instance of my DB class:

```
            DB entry = new DB(MainActivity.this);
            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry(description, reps, weight);
            entry.close();
```

open() uses the SQLiteOpenHelper and sets up database:

```
public DB open()
{
    sqlHelper = new dbHelper(sqlContext);
    sqlDB = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

But when I call this method:

> entry.createEntry(description, reps, weight);

I get following error:

(1) near "Table": syntax error

E/SQLiteDatabase(19344): Error inserting Description=test Weight=tesz Reps=test

E/SQLiteDatabase(19344): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Table": syntax error

(code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Table(Description,Weight,Reps) VALUES (?,?,?)

Comment: Please share the value of `DATABASE_TABLE` String

Comment: private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Table";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TABLE is a [reserved word in SQL](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html); you should not use it as the name of the table.

Try changing it to:

```
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "myTable";
```